# Find the local maxima and minima of $ f(x,y) = x^3+y^3 $ in $ g(x,y) = x^2+y^2-1 $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while but I seem to get to the wrong answer every time.
My steps are the following:

I have to find the solution to the system:
$$ \begin{cases}
               \nabla f = \lambda \nabla g \\
               g(x,y)=0,
   \end{cases} $$
and that is
$$ \begin{cases}
               3x^2 = 2 \lambda x\\
               3y^2 = 2 \lambda y \\
               x^2+y^2-1=0.
   \end{cases} $$
But now, when I try to solve for $ (x,y,\lambda) $, I keep getting stuck.

I have the feeling that I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere, or assuming something that isn't quite right.

If anyone could give me some ideas, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think you are wrong - seems OK to me.  To solve, consider two cases, (1), where one of the variables is zero, and (2) where no variable is zero.  You should get $(x, y, z) \in \{(0, 1, \frac32 ), (1, 0, \frac32), (\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2} , \frac3{2\sqrt2}), (-\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2} , -\frac3{2\sqrt2}) \} $, from which you can hunt for maxima/minima.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I was having a sign error...
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with what you properly wrote $$\begin{cases}
               3x^2 = 2 \lambda x\\
               3y^2 = 2 \lambda y 
   \end{cases}$$ you have four solutions, namely 
$$\left\{x= \frac{2 \lambda }{3},y= 0\right\},\{x= 0,y=
   0\},\left\{x= 0,y= \frac{2 \lambda }{3}\right\},\left\{x= \frac{2 \lambda
   }{3},y= \frac{2 \lambda }{3}\right\}$$ Just use them in the last equation $x^2+y^2-1=0$. You can discard the second one.

The first and third solutions would give $1=\frac{4 \lambda ^2}{9}$ while the fourth would give $1=\frac{8 \lambda ^2}{9}$.

Just continue.

Comment: Thanks!! :) I was having a sign error, that's why I had the solution wrong.

Comment: @SantiMontouliu. You are welcome ! As long as you find it, it is fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

$$x(3x-2\lambda )=0$$
$$y(3y-2\lambda )=0$$

Case $1$: $x=0$, then the problem become optimizing $y^3$ subject to $y^2=1$.

Case $2$, $y=0$,  then the problem become optimizing $x^3$ subject to $x^2=1$.

Case $3$: $x \neq 0, y \neq 0$, then we have $x=y$ and $x^2+y^2=1$.Hence $x=y = \frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Remark:

If we use polar coordinate, the problem become optimizes $\cos^3(\theta) + \sin^3(\theta)$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that alternative solution too :)